# Request receive timestamp w/o application layer code

Tags: java, servlets, request

I want to basically monitor the server calls on java side. So is there any way I can directly obtain the timestamp when request was received .

In other words,I do not want to explicitly make Date Objects and find out the timestamp. Rather I am interested if there's any timestamp parameter utility provided with Request Object.

Something provided by ServletActionContext.getRequest() or any available solution without the need to code to create Date() objects and find out.

The reason I am saying is I have around 50-60 server calls and may be even more in future in my application so each time i need code in application layer rather use this ready-made facility.

Comment: What exactly is the plan to monitor the server call? If this can be delayed job or typical post action analysis job why not use Logger?

Comment: and have you determined that those Date instances are costing a lot of cpu time per request?  I suspect it's a tiny fraction of the socket i/o time.

Comment: Exactly, I suspect, creation of 50 to 60 data object is not a big toll on CPU or Memory.

Comment: First of all, what is that you are trying to achieve. Log the time in some log file.

Answer (score 6):

[HttpServletRequest.getDateHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getDateHeader%28java.lang.String%29) gives you a timestamp as a `long` value.

Although this is from the request header and *not* the received time, it might work since it provides milliseconds since the epoch.

You can also look into [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), which allows you to

> Examples that have been identified for this design are:

1. Authentication Filters
2. *Logging and Auditing Filters*
   ...

[Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654) might be another facility, where you can hook into the processing of a servlet.

Back to your question:

ServletActionContext.getRequest() -> HttpServletRequest.getSession() ->
[HttpSession.getLastAccessedTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getLastAccessedTime%28%29)

> Returns the last time the client sent a request associated with this session, as the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 GMT, and marked by the time the container received the request.

Comment: I suspect `getDateHeader` utilizes `Date` class to return `long` value. So I don't think its any different.